# Postgres trigger when any of "top" rows change

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table with about 10,000 users. I want to watch the top 10, as sorted by `score`, and give realtime updates whenever the composition of the list changes or any of the scores of the top 10 change.

What's the best way to do this with a trigger, and will this be a highly expensive trigger to keep running?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have an index on `score`, it would be cheap to have an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger `FOR EACH ROW` that contains:

```
IF (SELECT count(*)
    FROM (SELECT 1
          FROM users
          WHERE score > NEW.score
          LIMIT 10
         ) top_users
   ) < 10
  OR
   (SELECT count(*)
    FROM (SELECT 1
          FROM users
          WHERE score > OLD.score
          LIMIT 10
         ) top_users
   ) < 10
THEN
   /* your action here */
END IF;
```

You'd also need a `DELETE` trigger that contains only the second part of the query and an `INSERT` trigger with only the first part.

The problem I see here is `/* your action here */`.
This should be a short operation like adding something to a queue, otherwise you might end up with long transactions and long locks.

Comment: How do I connect up the data with the return procedure? For example, to send one row I'm using `FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE` in the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement. Is this the problem you've identified with `/* your action here */` ? I'm new to Postgres so the more details you can provide the better.

Comment: Yes, it would be a `FOR EACH ROW` trigger. My doubt was that I don't know what you plan to do in the trigger. It should be nothing that - say - synchronously initiates a refresh in the front end. What do you mean with *connect up the data with the return procedure*?